# texture is not going on the outside of my rock object only the inside

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm using blender 2.77 fracture version.

1. The texture does not show in final render and when I'm in object mode. when I'm in edit mode it shows [image]
   This is in object mode after UV unwrap
   [image]
   This is inside the cube
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe nobody has the answer for this

Answer (score 2):

I have been checking your blend and it looks like the normals of the fractured object just point inwards instead of outwards (Recalculate Normal -> then it should work again, and of course re-execute Fracture)

I also took the liberty to tweak your blend a bit. As the rock texture was not packed, i just put the bottle texture onto the fractured object as well, just for demonstration. For example I used triggers and constraints, and reduced the displacement a bit, because the displacement "happens" after the physics and the more displacement you have, the more unnatural the shards will behave.

[image]

Edit: to have an "inside" actually, you need a solidify modifier on top and a Fracture Modifier below it, and need to refracture. The "inside" of the solidified object counts as "outside" too and will have the same material as the "real" outside of the cube. Additionally you could set an "inner material" on the Fracture Modifier and refracture. This will be applied to the inner shard faces.

Comment: not really what I mean, I need the whole cube to be textured not just one side I need it to look like rock outside, inside, edges of shards. As I appreciate the tweak my question was about the texture.

Comment: Duh I figured it out just had to add outside and inside uv mapping with two materials.